# Name of fastening metal pieces holding the cardboard back to a picture frame?

Tags: terminology

What do you call those thin metal pieces that fold to fasten the cardboard back on a picture frame?

Answer (score 10):

Points

[image: Points]

Thin metal tabs used to hold the mat, mount board and/or glazing inside of wood picture frames. Some points are stiff while others are flexible to allow access into the frame.

https://www.framedestination.com/media/wysiwyg/points_1.jpg

Comment: For the simplest fixings at the edge of a frame. **brads** and **gimp pins** are small, headless nails; **sprigs** are blue steel, often triangular.

Comment: Happy to give this a +1: the OP wasn't clear about whether he wanted generic terms or industry jargon.

Answer (score 7):

If you're asking about something like this:

[image]

then they are **clips**. This image is from a page advertising ["Wood picture frame spring clips"](http://www.webpictureframes.com/product4/1894/wood_picture_frame_spring_clips_woodspgsm20.html) from webpictureframes.com.

Other designs are available, including those which fit into a slot in the frame. This type isn't very adjustable for different thicknesses of cardboard but they are still *clips* (as are the hanging clips also shown here):

[image]

(Image from [dataliteframes.co.uk](http://www.dataliteframes.co.uk/bulk-supply-frames-options-extras.html))

Comment: Happy to do the same on this answer.  Between us we nailed it.